# in install4j, how to change the Java to a new version?

Tags: java, swing, install4j

I have purchased a license to use install4j.
I see in the generate script, we first define the JVM below

JVM_64="windows-amd64-1.7.0_51"

Later, in the template, we define the searchSequence below:

```xml
    <searchSequence>
        <registry />
        <envVar name="JAVA_HOME" />
        <envVar name="JDK_HOME" />
    </searchSequence>
```

If I want to upgrade Java to a new version, should I just change the version after windows-amd64 in JVM_64 and point JAVA_HOME to the new version?

Comment: 1) Don't include sigs. in questions (or answers). It is noise. 2) Can't speak for Install4J, but if an app. is deployed using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info), it will always get to use the most up to date JRE installed.

Answer (score 0):

It's in `ProjectStructure` and then `Project SDK`:[image]

If you want to add another, use the `New` button.

Answer (score 0):

The bundled JRE is configured on the "Bundled JRE" step of the media wizard. To use a different JRE bundle you first have to download it via `Project->Download JREs` and then choosing the new bundle in the media wizard. Just changing the version number in the project file will not work unless the bundle has already been downloaded.